# Why don't Python and Ruby make a distinction between declaring and assigning a value to variables?

Tags: python, ruby, languages, dynamic

Two of the most popular dynamically typed scripting languages, Python and Ruby, do not make a distinction in syntax between the declaration of a variable and assignation of a value to it.

That is in both languages, declaring a variable `n` and assigning a value to it would look like so:

```
n = 10
```

And assigning a new value to the variable later on would look just the same.

This creates two major problems:

1. A typo in a variable's name when changing it's value would create a new variable and cause bugs.
2. It makes the intentions of the code less clear. Hard to know where a variable is first declared and used, might make the code more confusing.

What I don't understand is why these languages don't have a `var` keyword to use on declaration, to make a distinction between a declaration and an assignment. This doesn't make the language any less dynamically typed, and I see no drawbacks.

What is the advantage of not having to explicitly define a variable?

Comment: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables  Found on http://stackoverflow.com/a/664352/508593

Comment: @Akash That does not seem related to the question at all, it remains equally valid if run through `s/variable/name/g`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a user rather (than designer) of Python there are three reasons I'm happy with this decisions:

Chiefly, it reads better. Of course I have to consciously decide to introduce a new variable when *writing*, but code is read far more often than it is written. A lot of code is simple in the sense that control flow and nesting has no influence on the meaning and existence of variables. When I read

```
it = Snark()
message = "A letter, not signed"
if random.random() > 0.5:
    hunt(it)
    message += " (by the Knave)"
return [it, message]
```

then I usually don't really care which (if any) mention of a name first introduces it, I just care that it's there and what happens to it.

Note that a significant body of pseudo code uses the same convention (no declaration, implicit introduction via assignment), and Python is often described as executable pseudo code, only half-jokingly. Four extra characters for *every* local variable does, to my spoiled eyes, feel like significant clutter in the context of Python, especially when it doesn't *feel* like it adds any value (see below); this would be lessened by a `:=` operator as in Go.

Second, I have yet to encounter a typo bug (due to this specific feature) that didn't also show itself in another clear manner. Maybe I'll change my mind in a few more years when I've encountered some bugs of this kind, but so far it's way, way down on my list of things that cause bugs. There's a fair number of questions about `UnboundLocalError` and it's a bit tricky to explain to beginners, but the frequency and popularity of those questions, compared to other gotchas (mutable default parameters, reference semantics, class vs. instance variables) indicates it's a rare problem.

Finally, the intent thing... sorry but I can't really understand this one. When reading and writing Python, it's always perfectly clear: What you assign to is intended as a local, unless loudly and explicitly declared otherwise. No question about it. Moreover, since (at least in Python) a variable is either local for the *entire* function or *not at all*, you can't have tricky code that uses a local variable in one branch and a global one in another. You see a name being assigned to? You instantly know it was *always* local from the beginning. Well, unless the code is broken in a very special way (and will throw the dreaded `UnboundLocalError` at run time, when entering those cases).

Comment: Here is an example of a bug in PHP caused by lacking declarations, from a practical case:

`$a = [1, 2, 3];
foreach ($a as $k => &$v) $v++; foreach ($a as $k => $v) echo "$k => $v\n";`

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh I don't know PHP well enough to identify the cause, would you mind explaining?

Comment: Please see [this my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24903006/3814740). As you see, it was unexpected for quite a number of people, me including, so that I had to experiment a lot. Now imagine how many incorrect programs there are out there due to such a bug.

Comment: BTW, your main argument is: what matters in a program is how it _reads_ (it's written once and read many), and for this no need to declare things. I disagree: I think what matters most is how it _executes_ -- whether it produces correct results. I even suspect that in case of scripting languages the majority of programs (which are small programs) are written once, debugged many, and read never -- that is, the most part of the effort is in writing and debugging, not in reading. Reducing bugs is the main purpose of a language.

Comment: Another argument against this answer: an indirect evidence of whether declarations are useful for humans in reading is that in most human languages it's obligatory to indicate with every use of a word (=variable) whether a it introduces a new object or refers to an existing one. In English we use articles `a` and `the` for this -- obligatorily with each use of each noun! In other languages there are other means, but the phenomenon seems to be universal. Humans should extremely need articles (=declarations) to avoid misunderstandings (=bugs).

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh Note that the bug you describe is due to an interaction of several PHP features (chiefly references) and IIUC can't happen in that way in other languages lacking declarations. As for writing/debugging: Note that most debugging strategies (from low-tech "staring at it until it becomes clear" to fancy time-traveling debuggers) include a significant chunk of reading the code being debugged.

Comment: Which is one more argument for a language to prevent the need in debugging in the first place.

Comment: How's that? I mean, I completely agree that it's better to not have bugs in the first place (I just don't see declarations helping with that to any significant degree). However, the need to read the code doesn't make debugging even less desirable: Reading is an integral part of debugging, it's already accounted for (consciously or not) in our feeling that it's hard work and takes a long time and is generally undesirable. If anything, this connection elevates the importance of *readability* since even debugging benefits from it.

Comment: Completely agree: readability is extremely important. You agree that preventing bugs is important. You disagree with that declarations help preventing bugs. I disagree with that declarations hurt readability. Perhaps we can agree to disagree :-)

Comment: Would you be opposed to the idea of being able to syntactically distinguish the three cases: (1) I don't expect any variable already exists with this name, and if one does the code is overwriting something it shouldn't so execution should trap; (2) I expect that I'm updating something that already exists with this name, and if it doesn't the code isn't updating what it's supposed to so execution should trap; (3) I want this to create or update the thing in question as appropriate.  There are times when #3 really is most useful, but...

Comment: ...even when reading code I would think it would be helpful to know which of the above was intended in case context doesn't make it clear.

Comment: @supercat Of course I would be opposed, first because of what I wrote in the question, second because *two* additional syntax constructs has all the downsides of *one* additional syntax constructs, only more so, and third because your case (1) strikes me as underachieving: If such a check is made, it can and should be made before execution.

Comment: @delnan: The existence of syntactic options for the first two would not imply that code that wanted #3 couldn't keep using the existing syntax.  Given the dynamic nature of Python (not sure about Ruby) I'm not quite sure how #1 could consistently be detected prior to execution.

Comment: Oh, nevermind about #1, I misread. And it's not about who gets to use `=` but that there are three options to begin with. Each and every language feature has to pull its weight, and two of these three do not IMHO.

Answer (score -3):

It's not that defining a variable is the same as assigning to it -- it's that the variables are not defined at all.  It's called [Dynamic Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_typing#Dynamic_type-checking_and_runtime_type_information).

You can't have a dynamically typed language that lets you define a variable, because that's what dynamic typing *is*.

The decision to do this completely changes the nature of the parser, and results in a completely different sort of language.  The principal difference to the end-user is usually that, when defining a function, your parameters turn out to be any type at all ("duck typing"), which is both a blessing, in that it makes your code much simpler, and a curse, in that it allows for a multitude of new ways that your code can fail.

I'm no compiler expert but I think it's also true that Dynamic Typing has major implications for the flavour of OOP you get in a language.

Comment: You are in error. JavaScript in strict mode requires you to use variables prior to using them. It is, however, dynamically typed. One has nothing to do with the other. Dynamic typing means that your variable can hold a value of any type. It has nothing to do with whether or not you have to define it. Likewise, a statically typed language with type inference would allow using variables without the need to define them. These two things are orthogonal.